# Page Numbers in Custom Quote Theme of Hubspot

Tags: pdf, hubspot, hubspot-crm

I am working on a customer quote theme on hubspot. I want to add page numbers in pdf when I download any quote as PDF from HubSpot. I have added all possible variations but nothing seem to work. Can anyone guide me here.

```
@bottom-left {
  content: "Page " counter(page) " of " counter(pages);
}
@page: right {
  @bottom-right {
    counter-increment: page;

    content: counter(page);
  }
}

@page: left {
  @bottom-left {
    counter-increment: page;

    content: counter(page);
  }
}

@page: left {
  @bottom-left {
    counter-increment: page;

    content: "Page " counter(page) " of " counter(pages);
  }
}
```

Comment: Then how do I add page numbers to pdf @KJ